# Retrofit returns null response body

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, gson

I am trying to follow a android tutorial on using `Retrofit`. I want to download some `JSON` from the server. The model for `JSON object` is `Animal class`. When I run this code I get `null` response body with error code of 406.

Inside `OnActivityCreated()` method of Fragment class:

```
Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("baseurl").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

AnimalApiInterface animalApiInterface=retrofit.create(AnimalApiInterface.class);
Call<List<Animal>> call=animalApiInterface.getStream();    
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Animal>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Animal>> call, Response<List<Animal>> response) {
        if (response.body() == null){
            Log.e("Error",response.code()+"");
            return;
        }

        for (Animal animal : response.body()) {
            Log.e("Zoo", animal.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Animal>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("Zoo", "Retrofit error " + t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Model class:

```
public class Animal implements Parcelable {

    private String name;
    private String species;
    private String description;
    private String thumbnail;
    private String image;

    public Animal(){}
    public Animal(String description, String image, String name, String species, String thumbnail) {
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.species = species;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }
    public Animal(Parcel source){
        name=source.readString();
        species=source.readString();
        description=source.readString();
        thumbnail=source.readString();
        image=source.readString();
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    //other getters and setters

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        applyDefaultValues();
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(species);
        dest.writeString(description);
        dest.writeString(thumbnail);
        dest.writeString(image);
    }

    private void applyDefaultValues() {
        if(name==null)name="";
        if(species==null)species="";
        if(description==null)description="";
        if(thumbnail==null)thumbnail="";
        if(image==null)image="";

    }

    public static Creator<Animal> CREATOR = new Creator<Animal>() {
        @Override
        public Animal createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Animal(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Animal[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Animal[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Interface

```
public interface AnimalApiInterface {
    @GET("/exhibits.json")
    Call<List<Animal>> getStream() ;
}
```

I have included all the required dependencies. The error body also a `empty String`. Ho can I solve this problem?

Comment: HTTP Error 406 mean  "server can only return content that is not acceptable to client because of 'Accept' header included in request.". Can you put up a full log (both request and response log).

Ref : https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#/4xx_Client_Error

Comment: can you try taking your code out of OnActivity and putting it in another method then call that method just before you return the view